# How not to enable bluetooth with hw-wireless switch?

Tags: 11.04, bluetooth, thinkpad

My laptop has hardware switch for enabling and disabling wireless adapters. This includes both bluetooth and wlan. I rarely use bluetooth and would like to keep it disabled (soft blocked) unless I manually enable it. Is this possible?

`rfkill list` when HW-switch disabled:

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

HW-switch enabled:

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
7: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

This is what I would like to have when HW-switch is enabled:

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have ThinkPad X61s with Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 3):

To add a soft-block you would use the syntax:

```
sudo rfkill block bluetooth
```

To unblock:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Possibly, if the softblock isnt remembered after a reboot I think you can run this without sudo on Natty

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

If the above works for you, you can add this as part of your start-up applications.

Comment: Using the hw-switch unblocks bluetooth even if it's manually soft blocked.

Comment: This however works if I have hardware switch enabled when I boot so it does help a bit.

Comment: Seppo - not sure what you mean "help a bit" - can you add to your question what the new values are when hardware switch is enabled and what happens when you block/unblock as above.  Thanks.

Comment: Running `sudo rfkill block bluetooth` results in the desired state where bluetooth is soft blocked. However if I disable hw-switch and reenable it then bluetooth is no longer blocked.

Comment: It helps a bit as I created a startup task that disables bluetooth. However this doesn't help if hw-switch is disabled during boot-up and I enable it after booting as bluetooth gets reenabled.

Comment: ok - understand - to be honest, that is what I would have expected - the hardware switch takes precedence over a soft-block and should do what you have observed.